# How to split text based on specific word

Tags: php, text, split

I have a text which contains the word "Article" many times for example:

> My text title Article 1 bla bla Article 2 bla bla ...

I want to split the text like this:

```
Text1=Article 1 bla bla
Text2=Article 2 bla bla
...
```

Comment: Question isn't clear. Is `bla bla` part of the article title? Are they always Article with a number suffix? Can the title be multiple words?

Comment: Rephrased your question; have a look to see if that's still what you mean :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to find a split pattern, you should look for a matching pattern:

```
/Article.*?(?=Article|$)/
```

It matches `Article`, followed by anything up to but not including another `Article` or end of line.

```
$str = 'some ething Article 1 2 3 Article 5 6 7';

preg_match_all('/Article.*?(?=Article)/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Article 1 2 3 
    [1] => Article 5 6 7
)
```

**Edit**

To just filter out the `Article` followed by a number:

```
preg_match_all('/Article \d+/', $str, $matches);
// $matches[0] contains "Article 1" and "Article 5"
```

Answer (score 2):

The most simple way would be using `explode`
http://php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php

```
$text = "article 1 text text article 2 text 123";
$articles = explode("article", $text);
```

then you have an array with the text after each "article" (without the word article!)

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
$articles = explode("article", $text);

$text1 = $articles[0];

$text2 = $articles[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with:

```
$parts = preg_split("/(?=Article\b)/",$text);
```

[Docs](https://www.php.net/preg-split)

Answer (score 0):

Hope one of these helps:

```
     $str = "My text title Article 1 bla bla Article 2 bla bla";

     $strArray = explode('Article', $str);

     echo '<pre>';
     print_r($strArray);
     echo '</pre>';

     $strArray = split('Article', $str);

     echo '<pre>';
     print_r($strArray);
     echo '</pre>';

     $strArray = preg_split("/(?=Article\b)/",$str);

     echo '<pre>';
     print_r($strArray);
     echo '</pre>';
```